# Modify and save data in JSON file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

First of all here's my **.json** file:

```
{           
    "ids": [1,2],
    "names": ["John Richards", "Doe Williams"],                     
    "skills": [ "Senior Software Engineer", "Junior Software Developer"]

}
```

And here's my ajax call to display each name from the object.

```
$.ajax({ 
    dataType: "json",
    url: "entries.json",
    success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.names.length; i++){
            console.log(data.names[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

I have a form with 3 fields and a button which I'm using to submit new data. The problem is that I can't modify that json file and submit that data.

```
$("#add").on("click",function(){
                var url = "entries.json";   

                //Form input
                var id = $("#empID").val();
                var fullName = $("#empFullName").val();
                var prof = $("#empProf").val();

                var entry = {   "ids":id, 
                                "names":fullName, 
                                "skills":prof 
                            };
                ....
                Ajax call for modification of the json file?!?!
```

What I mean by modify is to basically insert the **id**, **fullName** and **prof** into the corresponding field of the json and **save** it with the new values **appended**. Any insight? I'm stuck. Pulling is fine. How do I push data to the .json file? If I missed to provide anything important please let me know. I'm relatively new working with ajax.

Thanks in advance!

*P.S:I've already made the project using a database if anyone's wondering.*

Comment: you can't access file from the remote filesystem for modification. Consider using PHP(or another server-side lang) or Node.js

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Understood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write to a JSON file using only JavaScript in the browser. But with JavaScript in the browser you can write [Document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) and also write in the [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Writing in the localStorage of the browser:

```
// Form input
var id = $("#empID").val();
var fullName = $("#empFullName").val();
var prof = $("#empProf").val();

var obj = {
    "ids": id,
    "names": fullName,
    "skills": prof
};
localStorage.setItem('myJavaScriptObject', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

And than to retrieve the object, from the localStorage, you can do:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myJavaScriptObject'))
```

Other thing you can do is to create a service in the backend with a server-side technology like: NodeJS, Ruby on Rails, PHP, JAVA, etc... to handle the writing data in the JSON file.

- And then from the browser, making a `POST` request that sends the form inputs data to the endpoint of your service, the data can be saved into the JSON file.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks dude!! :)